# Modify this program so that before it creates the window, it prompts the user to enter the desired background color

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, turtle-graphics

When I write a script and run it. `Python Terminal starts doing it, but when it comes to prompting a color my program skips this step.`

The goal is:   `Modify this program so that before it creates the window, it prompts the user to enter the desired background
color. It should store the user’s responses in a variable, and modify the color of the window according to the
user’s wishes.`(Hint: you can find a list of permitted color names at http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/colors.
htm. It includes some quite unusual ones, like “peach puff” and “HotPink”.)```

`I mean that I want to run all this script in one click and when it comes to prompt me for this color it have to stop and wait for my input.`

Executed in Powershell

> > > color = str(input("Background color: "))
> > >        `It thinks that input is the next line ---> Background color: window = turtle.Screen()`

```
import turtle

color = str(input("Background color: "))

window = turtle.Screen()

window.bgcolor(color)
window.title("Hello, Tess!")

tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue")
tess.pensize(3)

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to run all this script in one click and when it comes to prompt
>   me for this color

In this case, I recommend you do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

window = Screen()

color = None

while color is None:
    color = window.textinput("Choose a background color", "Color:")

window.bgcolor(color)
window.title("Hello, Tess!")

tess = Turtle()
tess.color("blue")
tess.pensize(3)

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

window.mainloop()
```

The `textinput()` method was introduced in Python 3 and takes the console out of the interaction.  On my Unix system, if I add magic comment first line (e.g. `#! /usr/local/bin/python3`) and set the file to executable, I can (double) click on it and get prompted for the background color.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to run this code? control+V?
If so, then it most certainly would consider the next line to be the "input"

try copying this to a file (ex: turtle_test.py) and running `python turtle_test.py` in your powershell. I just did that and it ran normally (sort of, considering the last line is wrong).

Last thing (for python2): `turtle.mainloop()` is supposed to used instead of `window.mainloop()`. In python3 it's correct, though

Comment: I'm running it by shift + enter

Comment: In Python 3, as the OP tagged this question, `window.mainloop()` is valid.  Try copying this code to a file (ex: turtle_test.py) and running `python3 turtle_test.py` and it should run normally, as the the last line is correct.

Comment: changed it there, thanks for the correction!, @cdlane

Answer (score 0):

It successfully prompts me for color and successfully implements various options using a Bash shell.

```
➜ python3 stackoverflow_question.py
  Background color: peach puff
```

Comment: In my case, it doesn't ask for this color and it implements next line of code to choose this color...

Comment: I mean that I want to run all this script in one click and when it comes to prompt me for this color it have to stop and wait for my input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle 

wn = turtle.Screen()     
bkgnd_colour = str(input("Enter your background colour"))  
wn.bgcolor(bkgnd_colour) 


   
tess = turtle.Turtle()  
t_colour = str(input("Enter your desired colour of the Turtle"))  
tess.color(t_colour)

s_ize = str(input("Enter the width of your pen"))  
tess.pensize(int(s_ize))
         
tess.forward(50)  
tess.left(120)  
tess.forward(50)  
tess.left(120)  
tess.forward(50)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This will help ya out, and it works successfully. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
#it solves the both problems with input and the other instances of the 
#turtles.
#It take the input from the user for the first turtle name 'anish' and the  
#other instance 'nainesh' have his own attributes.

from tkinter import mainloop
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
bg_color = str(input("Enter your desire color for your background: "))
wn.bgcolor(bg_color)

title_left = str(input("Enter your desire title for the window: "))
wn.title(title_left)
anish = turtle.Turtle()
anish_color = str(input("Enter the color of the turtle: "))
anish.color(anish_color)
anish_pen_size = str(input("Enter the pen size of the turtle: "))
anish.pensize(anish_pen_size)

anish.forward(50)
anish.left(90)
anish.forward(30)
anish.left(90)
anish.forward(100)
anish.left(90)
anish.forward(30)
anish.left(90)
anish.forward(50)

nainesh = turtle.Turtle()
nainesh.color("black")
nainesh.pensize(7)

nainesh.forward(100)
nainesh.left(90)
nainesh.forward(100)
wn.mainloop()
```